# PhoneGap: Add CordovaWebView to DroidGap

Tags: android, webview, cordova

I would like to embed a CordovaWebView to the class which extends DroidGap.

TestActivity.java:

```
public class TestActivity extends DroidGap {
    private static CordovaWebView webView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("<local page link - index.html>");

        //Create CordovaWebView
        webView = new CordovaWebView(this);
        webView.loadUrl("<remote page link>");

        //Get the current layout and add the CordovaWebView to it
        RelativeLayout rootRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ((FrameLayout) root.getParent()).removeAllViews();
        rootRelativeLayout.addView(root);
        rootRelativeLayout.addView(webView);
        setContentView(rootRelativeLayout);
    }
}
```

The remote page can be displayed in CordovaWebView but PhoneGap API cannot be invoked.
However, if I load the remote page in `super.loadUrl("<remote page link>")` directly. The API can be invoked successfully. May I know what is the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Here is the log in LogCat. It seems that `onMessage` is not being called.

```
06-12 17:05:06.554: D/CordovaWebView(5102): >>> loadUrl(<remote page link>)
06-12 17:05:06.554: D/PluginManager(5102): init()
06-12 17:05:06.554: D/CordovaWebView(5102): >>> loadUrlNow()
06-12 17:05:11.519: I/GATE(5102): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
06-12 17:05:26.559: E/CordovaWebView(5102): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? DroidGap already creates a CordovaWebView by default.  This just seems completely unnecessary!

Comment: The reason is that I would like to add two CordovaWebView, one is default webview and another is the custom webview. And the custom webview is able to call the PhoneGap API.